# Endpoints in GAE connected Android client

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Does anyone know how to configure this correctly in Eclipse? Somehow I have both google-api-client-1.16.0-rc.jar (as an example) and 1.17 libs on the client. The 1.16 libs are generated by the GAE project when generating endpoints, not sure how the 1.17 libs got there. If I delete all the 1.16 libs on the client the app runs fine but I would really like to configure to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't mess with the libs generated for cloud endpoints.  If it generates 1.16 then that is what endpoints is tested with, and probably what everyone else using endpoints is using. And I believe 1.16 is correct anyway - that's what my projects are using.  The fact that it is one version behind (1.17 is current) is not a problem really - the google java client libraries have changed very little over the last few versions.

You can make sure you have the latest GPE (and you probably do since you get notified when updates are available), since this plays a role in endpoints, but like I said, I think 1.16 is correct for endpoints.

If you need Google Java Client Library for your own stuff, in the same project, I would personally stick to that same version - 1.16 - but you don't have to.

Comment: You're probably right. The 1.17's came in for Chromecast. I'm sticking with them as it seems to work but just have to delete the 1.16's whenever I regenerate endpoints.